# ui-grid ignores my custom row template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ui-grid

My goal is to have a listener for cell/row mouse hover

Any thoughts why my implementation of ui-grid ignores my `rowTemplate` and loads the default one?

**Let me know what else I need to provide to make it easier for you guys to help me.**

I have an MVC.net (C#) web app with angular js, I am loading the ui-grid through the `BundleConfig`

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
                 "~/scripts/angular/angular.js",
                 "~/scripts/angular/angular-route.js",
                 "~/scripts/angular/angular-resource.js",
                 "~/scripts/ui-grid.js"
                 ));
```

my ui-grid options

```
$scope.gridGroupCodeMapsOptions =
      {
         columnDefs: columns,
         data: $scope.codeMapResults.data,
         enableSorting: true,
         enableColumnMenus: false,
         flatEntityAccess: true,
         showGridFooter: true,
         gridFooterTemplate: "<div class='custom-footer'>{{grid.rows.length}} items</div>",
         rowTemplate: "app/codeMaps/groupCodeMapRowTemplate.html"
      }
```

my rowTemplate html:

```
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid"
 ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'"
 class="ui-grid-cell"
 ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }"
 role="{{col.isRowHeader ? 'rowheader' : 'gridcell'}}"
 ng-click="grid.scopeApp.notify()"
 ui-grid-cell>
```

the default rowTemplate html:

```
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid"
 ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'"
 class="ui-grid-cell"
 ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }"
 role="{{col.isRowHeader ? 'rowheader' : 'gridcell'}}"
 ui-grid-cell>
```

Things I tired:

- [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/adPdJ3n5ZAmA7yrm4rjP?p=preview): The rowTemplate works on a separate Plunker.
- stop/start my iis in case of any chached files
- Inline RowTemplate

Answer (score 0):

make sure your `groupCodeMapRowTemplate.html` path is accessible and correct

example:

> your app url: localhost:8000 
>   your template should be accessible using localhost:8000/app/codeMaps/groupCodeMapRowTemplate.html

Comment: Yes it does. I also tried to put it as an inline rowTemplate but got the same issue